# Как сделать кнопку поверх 3D объекта в Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Как сделать кнопку поверх 3D объекта в Unity 3D??
Пример ниже
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто знает урок или гайд о том, как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Найдем положение объекта на экране, и поместим туда кнопку:

```cs
using UnityEngine;


public class ObjectButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform target;
    [SerializeField] Transform button;
    [SerializeField] Camera cam;

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 targetOnScreen = calculateScreenPosition(target.position, cam);
        button.position = targetOnScreen;
        button.gameObject.SetActive(targetOnScreen != Vector3.zero);
    }

    private Vector3 calculateScreenPosition(Vector3 position, Camera camera)
    {
        Vector3 heading = position - camera.transform.position;
        if (Vector3.Dot(camera.transform.forward, heading) > 0)
        {
            return camera.WorldToScreenPoint(position);
        }
        return Vector3.zero;
    }
}
```

`target` - Объект который должен быть под кнопкой
`button` - Кнопка
`cam` - Камера в пространстве которой это должно происходить
Скрипт повесить на `target`.

Comment: Очень вам благодарен!!!